# Looking up multiple values from a pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas

I have been struggling to find an elegant way of looking up multiple values from a pandas DataFrame. Assume we have a dataframe `df` that holds the “result” `R`, that depends on multiple index keys, and we have another dataframe `keys` where each row is a list of values to look up from `df`. The problem is to loop over the keys and look up the corresponding value from `df`. If the value does not exist in `df`, I expect to get a `np.nan`.

So far I have come up with three different methods, but I feel that all of them lack elegance. So my question is there another prettier method for multiple lookups? Note that the three methods below all give the same result.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':range(5),
                   'B':range(10,15),
                   'C':range(100,105),
                   'R':np.random.rand(5)}).set_index(['A','B','C'])

print 'df'
print df

keys = pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,5],'B':[10,10,10],'C':[100,100,100]})
print '--'
print 'keys'
print keys

# By merge 
print '--'
print pd.merge(df.reset_index(), keys, on=['A','B','C'],how='right').reset_index().R

# By reindex
print '--'
print df.reindex(keys.set_index(['A','B','C']).index).reset_index().R

# By apply
print '--'
print keys.apply(lambda s : df.R.get((s.A,s.B,s.C)),axis=1).to_frame('R').R
```

Comment: I don't really see anything wrong with your merge approach - I guess it could be a little shorter as `df.merge(keys, left_index=True, right_on=['A','B','C'], how='right').R`?

Comment: Thanks! This starts to look nice. It will be even nicer if *not* doing a `set_index()` on `df` in which case the expression becomes simply `df.merge(keys, on=['A','B','C'], how='right').R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `update` is pretty.

```
result = keys.set_index( ['A','B','C']) # looks like R
result['R'] = pd.np.nan # add nan
```

Them use `update`

```
result.update(df)
                 R
A B  C            
0 10 100  0.068085
     100  0.068085
5 10 100       NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an even simpler solution:

```
keys = (pd.DataFrame({'A':[0,0,5],'B':[10,10,10],'C':[100,100,100]})
        .set_index(['A','B','C']))
keys['R'] = df
```

or similarly (and more chaining compatible):

```
keys.assign(R = df)
```

That's all that is needed. The automatic alignment of the index does the rest of the work! :-)